# Dell 1525 - Win 7 64bit - 2 x Data Interface Missing?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, dell-inspiron

I have just installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit SP1. I currently have 2 Data Interface with a yellow exclamation which means it's unrecognized and the drivers for it are missing.

I have installed all of the drivers found in this post on the dell forums:

en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3524/p/19262920/19445496.aspx

Windows update has been unable to find the missing drivers for the device and I can't figure out what the device could be.

I have a Dell Inspiron 1525. What could the Data Interface be?

### Device Manager:

[image: Device Manager:]

### Device Manager: View By Connection:

[image: Device Manager: View By Connection]

Comment: More than likely it is a (USB) wireless broadband card from AT&T, Verizon, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Do these refer to usb devices? I do not have a wireless device, but i do have a usb flash drive and wireless mouse using 2 ports... However, even with them removed these two entries still show up in the device manager?

Comment: See if this software can identify the device....http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the details page on the driver properties dialog look at the property "Hardware Ids". These are used to match a driver to a piece of hardware. Right click on one of them and select copy. Then google it or enter it into one of the various driver database web sites. Try the others if the first doesn't get any results.

[image]